# Customer progress bar not filling properly

Tags: c#

I created a simple progress bar for my C# Forms Application.  It loads and functions properly with the sole exception that it doesn't fill completely by the time it gets to 100%  It needs to go to 115% to complete.  I have no idea why its doing this.  Any insight, you could be my hero.  Here is the code:

```
    private void CustomProgressBar()
    {
        picBoxPB.Visible = true;
        width = picBoxPB.Width;
        height = picBoxPB.Height;
        Unit = width / 100;
        complete = 0;
        bmp = new Bitmap(width, height);
        t.Interval = 30;
        t.Tick += new EventHandler(this.t_Tick);
        t.Start();
    }

    private void t_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        graph = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
        graph.Clear(Color.DarkGoldenrod);
        graph.FillRectangle(Brushes.ForestGreen, new Rectangle(0,0,(int)(complete * Unit),height));
        graph.DrawString(complete + "%", new Font("Papyrus", height / 3), Brushes.Black, new PointF(width / 2 - height, height / 10));

        picBoxPB.Image = bmp;
        complete++;

        if (complete>100)
        {
            graph.Dispose();
            t.Stop();

        }
    }
```

Comment: using `if (complete>=100)` can fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without any more information all I can see is that you are incrementing the complete variable after you draw the graph.

A wild guess is you move the complete to the top of the method such as

```
private void t_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        complete++;
        graph = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
        graph.Clear(Color.DarkGoldenrod);
        graph.FillRectangle(Brushes.ForestGreen, new Rectangle(0,0,(int)(complete * Unit),height));
        graph.DrawString(complete + "%", new Font("Papyrus", height / 3), Brushes.Black, new PointF(width / 2 - height, height / 10));

        picBoxPB.Image = bmp;


        if (complete>100)
        {
            graph.Dispose();
            t.Stop();

        }
}
```

This assumption is made bearing no understanding of the `Unit` field (which appears to be a percentage of the `Width` field (not shown).

Answer (score 0):

You initialize `Unit` to be `width / 100` that's ok, but you do it in `CustomProgressBar()` and not where it is used.

If your control is used elsewhere, it will probably be resized. So the `width` will change. But you did not update `Unit` accordingly (nether your `Bitmap` object).

Yo have two option:

- Listen for size change and update `Unit` when the event occurs.
- Move your `Unit` variable in your `t_tick` function and compute it each time.

The second option cost a little more in time but the code readability is **way** better.

If you did not use the `Unit` variable elsewhere, choose the second option.

Also, if your goal is to draw a [custom control](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2016/Writing-your-Custom-Control-step-by-step), you should learn on how to overload [Control.OnPaint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.windows.forms.control.onpaint%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), using a bitmap is not the solution here.